# sed avoid replacing lines which start with @

Tags: regex, sed

I used `sed 's/^/LP1-/'` but this command also changed lines which start with @.

```
@SQ SN:NbV1Ch16     LN:148804966
@SQ SN:NbV1Ch17     LN:145611047
@SQ SN:NbV1Ch18     LN:144482707
@SQ SN:NbV1Ch19     LN:137831541
@RG ID:OZBenth8_.fastp.fq.gz        SM:OZBenth8_.fastp.fq.gz        LB:OZBenth8_.fastp.fq.gz        PL:ILLUMINA
@PG ID:bwa  PN:bwa  VN:0.7.17-r1188 CL:bwa mem OZBenth8_R1.fastp.fq.gz 
HWI-ST945_0069:8:1101:1475:2032#NNNNNN      99      NbV1Ch07        110148523       60      100M    =       110148853       430     CCAAAAAGCACAGCTGGACCAAACCGGCCCAAATATTGATAGCCGTCAGACTACGCCATGAGCGGAGTCCCCCAAGTTCGTTTGATAGAAAATTCAGGAC
    CCCFFFFFHHHHHJJJJJJJJJJJHJJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJIIJJJJJJJJHHHFFFDECEEDDDDDDDDDDDDACDEDDDDDDDEDDDDDDDDDDDDD    NM:i:0  MD:Z:100        MC:Z:100M       AS:i:100        XS:i:68 RG:Z:OZBenth8_.fastp.fq.gz
HWI-ST945_0069:8:1101:1475:2032#NNNNNN      147     NbV1Ch07        110148853       60      100M    =       110148523       -430    AATCTTCTTCCAATTCCATGGCGGCCCAAAGTCACACGGCCTCTTCACTTTCTGAGGTTGCAAGAAGAACCACACAAAAAATATTGGGGGCTAAAATCCC
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEC=FFFHHHJJJJJJJIJHGIJJIBJJJIIJJJIJJJJJFIHJHJJJJJJJJJJJJJHHHHHFFFFFCCC    NM:i:1  MD:Z:54T45      MC:Z:100M       AS:i:95 XS:i:65 RG:Z:OZBenth8_.fastp.fq.gz
HWI-ST945_0069:8:1101:1446:2101#NNNNNN      83      NbV1Ch16        133875416       44      100M    =       133874965       -551    ATATGTCTTATTCTTCTTCGACGAGTTTCAATCTAAAATTCAGTCAAAACCAAGTCTAATCTTCACCAAAACCCCTCAAAATTGAGATATAAACTCCTAA
    DDDDDD
```

How is it possible to exclude lines which start with `@` to be changed?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/^[^@]/LP1-&/'
```

Here, `^[^@]` matches the start of a line position with `^` and `[^@]` matches any char but `@`. `LP-&`  replaces the match with `LP1-` and the char that was matched with `[^@]`.

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/Gl6Nmi).

To also modify empty lines, use an alternation with a `$`, an end of line anchor:

```
sed -E 's/^([^@]|$)/LP1-&/'
```

Or BRE POSIX with GNU sed:

```
sed 's/^\([^@]\|$\)/LP1-&/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix the `s` command with a negated address:

```sh
sed -s '/^@/!s/^/LP1-/'
```

Answer (score 0):

by gnu sed,

```
sed 's/^([^@])/\1LP1-/'
```